# I need to capture the barcode value with QuaggaJS

Tags: barcode-scanner

I had gone through the API of QuaggaJs from [here](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/).

Then I had downloaded the demo and tried to run the 'file_input.html' from the examples folder. 
 According to the API after the capturing is completed. 
 It's supposed to call the Quagga.onDetected(callback) function.

I don't know what's the reason but its not happening.
Am I missing something over here?

Comment: did you try searching the web? what did you try to debug this problem? please [edit] your question to include these details.